# How to make jQuery 3.6.0 work with node.js v12.16.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, cdn

I am using an online IDE called [Replit](https://replit.com) and node.js projects run on the node version : 12.16.1 . But I am trying to get jQuery 3.6.0 to work with this version of node.js but with every methods I found online, non of them work. I am not using html though, but [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) which is a way to insert variables in an html file.

The first method I tried using was importing jQuery using **cdn** :

```
script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js', integrity='sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=', crossorigin='anonymous')
```

The second method is using the jQuery **npm** package :

```
const { JSDOM } = require( 'jsdom' );
const jsdom = new JSDOM();
const { window } = jsdom;
const { document } = window;
global.window = window;
global.document = document;

const $ = global.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
console.log( `jQuery ${jQuery.fn.jquery} working! Yay!!!` );
```

The console.log() does work but the code does not run correctly.

Here is the code :

```
const { JSDOM } = require( 'jsdom' );
const jsdom = new JSDOM();
const { window } = jsdom;
const { document } = window;
global.window = window;
global.document = document;

const $ = global.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );
console.log( `jQuery ${jQuery.fn.jquery} working! Yay!!!` );

const users = require('../../../data/user')
const sessions = require('../../../data/session')

let session = {}
let user = {}

$('#createSessionButton').on("click", async () => {
  session = await sessions.create({
    name: $('#session').val(),
    players: $('#players').val(),
    rewardMultiplier: $('#multiplier').val()
  })

  user = await users.create({
    session: session.name,
    username: $('#username').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    isAdmin: true,
    total: 0
  })
})

$('#joinSessionButton').on("click", async () => {
  session = await sessions.findOne({ name: $('#session').val() })

  user = await users.findOne({
    session: session.name,
    username: $('#username').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    password: $('#password').val()
  }) || await users.create({
    session: session.name,
    username: $('#username').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    password: $('#password').val(),
    isAdmin: false,
    total: 0
  })
})

module.exports = session, user
```

Basically, once a button is pressed, the text values of multiple input html tags are fetched, **using their ids (in pug you use the # to declare an id => example : h3#test Test == < h3 id="test">Test< /h3>)**, to be send to a database.

And here is one of the pug/jade files using this script :

```
doctype
html(lang="en")
  head
    include ../includes/header.pug
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/session.css")

  body
    h1.mb-3.font-weight-normal(style="margin-top: 7.5vw; margin-bottom: 5vw;") Please fill in each and everyone of these fields to create a session
      form(style="max-width: 480px; margin: auto;")

        h2.mt-5 Session Information
        h5 (This will create a session for you and your friends to play together)
        input#session.form-control.mb-3(type="text", placeholder="Session Name", required)
        input#players.form-control.mb-2(type="number", min='5', max='25', placeholder="Number of Players", required)
        input#multiplier.form-range(type='range', value="1", min='0.5', max='10', step='0.5', onchange="rangevalue.value = `Reward Multiplier : ${value}`")
        output#rangevalue.h4 Reward Multiplier : 1

        h2.mt-5 User Information
        h5 (This will create or fetch your account)
        input#username.form-control.mb-3(type="text", placeholder="Username", required)
        input#email.form-control.mb-3(type="email", placeholder="Email Address", required)
        input#password.form-control(type="password", placeholder="Password", required)

      div.mt-3.center
        a.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(href='/session') <-- Back
        a#createSessionButton.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(href="/session/dashboard") Create session -->
        
    script(src="/js/session.js")
```

But the jQuery does not work at all in my project, even though it works in the web browser console. If anyone could help me it would be really awesome !!!

Here is the link to the web browser : [Website](https://lesaffreux.xxgamecodingxx.repl.co/session/create)

Comment: So... Node.js is a server-side JavaScript runtime environment, not a web browser. It has no user interface, and therefore no way for a human to click on anything. Pug is a template language to generate HTML, which when served by Node, will be used by a web browser to render a user interface that a human could then click. Writing jQuery on the server side makes no sense because the clicks are occurring client side, on the browser, where the server doesn't know anything about them. I think you need to do a bit more studying.

Answer (score 0):

What @HereticMonkey said is true. The `script()` line at the top of your question is the right way to go, because it loads jquery into your *web page*, not your *server*. It loads it from a CDN. That's good.

jquery uses browser-side (client-side) javascript to manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM) of the stuff in your web page.

There's no DOM in your nodejs server (unless you're doing something extraordinary--you aren't) so jquery in the server is pointless.